# Grails: Turn off Codenarc NoDef rule for controller actions

Tags: grails, codenarc

Is there a way to turn off the Codenarc NoDef rule for Grails controller actions? The rule is a good practice to follow in general but since some actions return a value and some don't, we typically use def to support all variants. I looked around a bit to see if this rule can be turned off for controller actions but came up empty. Does anyone know?

Comment: "we typically use def to support all variants" - Be aware the if the method return type is `void`, per https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/bd7741b646e13da598926cf118fad0221590e567/grails-plugin-controllers/src/main/groovy/org/grails/compiler/web/ControllerActionTransformer.java#L303 it will not be configured as a controller action. I know that isn't what you are asking about, but want to point that out in case that might prove helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using codenarc plugin then I believe you should be able to disable some of the rules in codenarc rule set file as mentioned in this blog

http://www.tothenew.com/blog/grails-clean-code-configure-codenarc-plugin/

Comment: You cannot configure this specific Codenarc rule by filename. Check @j4y answer.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** exclude specifically Controller actions and you **can't** exclude by class name either (using the `doNotApplyToClassNames` property) because the rule is applied by file level and not class.

The closest I could get was to exclude the whole Controller from the rule like this:

```
NoDef.doNotApplyToFilesMatching = /.*Controller.groovy/
```

I also recommend excluding `Services` and `grailsApplication` injection from the rule, as it doesn't bother me to have defs there. For example:

```
class SomeService {
    def otherService
    def grailsApplication
}
```

The rule configuration for this should be:

```
NoDef.excludeRegex = /(.+Service|.+Controller|grailsApplication)/
```

Answer (score 1):

I read the blog post and tried the doNotApplyToClassNames option, but it didn't work.

From the documentation:

> NoDef Rule
>
> Since CodeNarc 0.22
>
> NOTE: This rule applies to the text contents of a file rather than a
>   specific class, so it does not support the applyToClassNames and
>   doNotApplyToClassNames configuration properties.

So you cant actually use the doNotApplyToClassNames parameter, but there is a `excludeRegex` property that you can use, but you would need to come up with a regular expression to exclude your controller actions.

> Regular expression describing names of attributes, parameters or
>   methods that could be precede by the def keyword.